# SQL query performance in JOIN

Tags: sql

I am working in SQL and has 26000 thousands of records in the primary key sql table.

**Employees Table data:**

```
    Id | Name | DepartmentId
   --------------------------
    1  | AA   |    1
    2  | BB   |    1
    3  | CC   |    2
```

**Departments table data:**

```
Id  | Name     |
----------------
1   |  IT      |
2   |  Network |
```

Created index for `Employee.DepartmentId`

I have a query as below,

```
Select E.Id, E.Name, E.DepartmentId
from Employees E
JOIN Department D
ON E.DepartmentId = D.Id
```

The above query executes in 2 seconds and returned all the records.
but when I included the department name in the select list it takes more time around 10 seconds.

```
Select E.Id, E.Name, E.DepartmentId,D.Name
from Employees E 
JOIN Department D
ON E.DepartmentId = D.Id
```

What is the issue here?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I removed the incompatible database tags.  Please tag the question with the database you are really using.

Comment: is your `DepartmentId` on `Employees` is indexed ? And remember you are selecting all the records and the returned data in JSON will be of big size and need to consider the network speed for transferring the data as well.

Comment: **[edit]** your question and add the execution plan. [_Formatted_](http://dba.stackexchange.com/help/formatting) text please, [no screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Comment: When you only select from Employees, then the database will remove the entire join operation during the opmimization phase

Comment: It will be very useful if you provide more information like which database are you using and the structure of all tables.

Comment: @Abhik Chakraborty, Yes both columns are indexed.

Answer (score 1):

For this query:

```
select E.Id, E.Name, E.DepartmentId, D.Name
from Employees E join
     Department D
     on E.DepartmentId = D.Id;
```

The optimal index is `Department(Id, Name)`.  You may already have essentially this index if `Department(Id)` is the primary key.

Perhaps a more important issue is the size of the result set.  The department name may be large (particularly if it is declared as a `char()` rather than a `varchar()`).  The issue may simply be the size of the department name.

Answer (score 1):

As alluded to by Gordon, it is not the join on the tables with the indexes that are the issue, rather the volume of data being returned in the result set (from the additional Department Name) that is either being displayed in the terminal or in the gui.

Additionally, you should also be able to use the EXPLAIN keyword in MySQL to help identify any index issues.